# Use of the operator And in VBscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, automated-tests

I have this code line in my function:

```
For Each objSheet1 In objWorkbook3.Sheets
    If objSheet1.Name <> "X" And objSheet1.Name <> "Y" And objSheet1.Name <> "Z" And objSheet1.Name <> "K" Then
        objSheet1.Delete
    End If
Next
```

The result is that my function deletes all the sheets where their name is different only to K as if only for this part `objSheet1.Name <> "K"` is accepted, I tried

```
For Each objSheet1 In objWorkbook3.Sheets
    If objSheet1.Name <> "X" And objSheet1.Name <> "Y" Then
        objSheet1.Delete
    End If
Next
```

It is working fine, is the use of more than 2 `And` in VBScript not acceptable?

How can I replace it please?

Comment: You are checking `objSheet1 <> "K"` Not  `objSheet1.Name <> "K"`

Comment: How I can check the name please ?

Comment: Is this not your code? Just modify the `objSheet1 <> "K"` to `objSheet1.Name <> "K"` as @SearchAndResQ suggested in the comment above. The rest of the conditions check the `Name` property but the last one doesn't so will never match.

Comment: The code you posted should delete all sheets in the workbook unless they're named X or Y or Z or K. If it doesn't work that way: please provide evidence that would allow us to reproduce the behavior. If that's not what you want: please elaborate on what you expect the code to do.

Comment: I need to delete all the sheets of objworkbook3 and save only those where their name is X or Y or Z or K

Comment: If your actual code does match the code in this post (including the latest updates to replace `objSheet1 <> "K"` to `objSheet1.Name <> "K"` and if you properly defined `objWorkbook3` as your `Workbook`, I can't see a reason why your code is not working. Make sure there is no typo in your actual code, make sure you have it updated as is in this post and if it still does not work, kindly do as requested in [Ansgar Wiechers' comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891455/use-of-the-operator-and-in-vbscript#comment67072550_39891455)

Comment: @sourh here's a friendly bit of advice, you need to be more vocal. A lot of suggests have been made and you although being active are not forth coming and not just on this question. It can be really frustrating for those trying to help you and doesn't show a huge amount of respect.

Comment: @Lankymart? This is not about respect because I have a technical problem with office, I'm solving it and then I have to check if the problem is solved or not. So, just I solve my problem with office and then I will try as soon as possible these propositions. Sorry for All.

Comment: @sourh that's fine and perfectly understandable, we all have deadlines and priorities to take care of, just a  quick update is all that is needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Please:

```
For Each objSheet1 In objWorkbook3.Sheets
    If objSheet1.Name <> "X" Then If objSheet1.Name <> "Y" Then If objSheet1.Name <> "Z" Then If objSheet1.Name <> "K" Then objSheet1.Delete
Next
```

Tested and it worked for me.!

Answer (score -2):

try using "&&" and not the word And

Like These:

For Each objSheet1 In objWorkbook3.Sheets
    If objSheet1.Name <> "X" && objSheet1.Name <> "Y" && objSheet1.Name <> "Z" &&  objSheet1.Name <> "K" Then objSheet1.Delete
Next

Comment: `&&` is NOT VBScript syntax.

Comment: thank you Rani but  as what Lankymart said, this is not a VBScript syntax.

Answer (score -3):

You can use parantheses () to make the execution as you intended. Such as this:

```
If (objSheet1.Name <> "X") And (objSheet1.Name <> "Y") And (objSheet1.Name <> "Z") and (objSheet1 <> "K") Then
    objSheet1.Delete 
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is the typo in the conditional as [@SearchAndResQ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1682881/searchandresq) points out [in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891455/use-of-the-operator-and-in-vbscript#comment67068939_39891455). Those brackets do not effect how the conditional is evaluated.

Comment: I can't understand your objective. Could you please rephrase your question ? Did you mean to delete all the sheets except sheet named "K" ? Is this right ?

Comment: How is **objWorkbook3** defined ? When I tried using **ActiveWorkbook.Sheets**, it worked perfectly for me. See my code below: ** For Each objSheet1 In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If (objSheet1.Name <> "Sheet1") And (objSheet1.Name <> "Y") And (objSheet1.Name <> "Z") And (objSheet1.Name <> "K") Then
           objSheet1.Delete
        End If
Next**

Comment: Thank you Prabhu, I was having a problem was in my Excel (technical problem) and after fixing it, I tested your  proposition, it is working but I think the problem was with my EXcel and not with the code.